# List with different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, list

could you explain how do you describe the following lists? I do not manage to understand why i have an error. I am trying to select only the 2nd array. 
I can select the 3rd array with `array[1]`
I can select the 1st and 2nd array with `array[0]`

But I do not manage to get only the second array.
I don't know if I am clear enough but I can add details. 
Any contribution would be appreciated.

The output:

```
[array([[0.01397856]]), array([[0.0139789 , 0.01397899, 0.01397964, 
0.01397926, 0.0139788 ,
    0.01397882, 0.01397953, 0.01398004, 0.01397629, 0.01398015,
    0.01397796, 0.01397703, 0.01397831, 0.01397893, 0.01398011,
    0.01397746, 0.01397834, 0.01397892, 0.01397887, 0.01397964,
    0.0139789 , 0.01397797, 0.01397756, 0.01397917, 0.01397798,
    0.01397689, 0.01397952, 0.01397637, 0.01397901, 0.01397878]])], 
array([0.         0.03333333 0.06666667 0.1        0.13333333 0.16666667
 0.2        0.23333333 0.26666667 0.3        0.33333333 0.36666667
 0.4        0.43333333 0.46666667 0.5        0.53333333 0.56666667
0.6        0.63333333 0.66666667 0.7        0.73333333 0.76666667
 0.8        0.83333333 0.86666667 0.9        0.93333333 0.96666667
 1.        ]))
```

Comment: Did you try using array[1][0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the brackets I understand you have something similar to this:

```
my_list = [["A", "B"], "C"]
```

To get all three elements:

```
print(my_list[0][0])
print(my_list[0][1])
print(my_list[1])
```